# Replace comma from a specific field in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, replace

I am trying to replace commas in a specific field in an array. For example I have below the following array which represents data collected from a csv file:

```
[
    {
      "Month/Year": "2019-09",
      "group": "blue",
      "flights": "668,620"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "blue",
        "flights": "662,520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-09",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "662,520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "678,520"
    }
]
```

**Desired**

```
[
    {
      "Month/Year": "2019-09",
      "group": "blue",
      "flights": "668620"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "blue",
        "flights": "662520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-09",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "662520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "678520"
    }
]
```

How can I run a cleaning operation on this JSON before I work with it? I am thinking when the JSON is brought in I treat it by cleaning it and then I can work with it for graphing purposes.

Comment: You likely don't have JSON at all, as JSON is a text format. What you've shown is an array of objects.

Comment: @HereticMonkey What do you mean? This is definitely JSON here

Comment: "definitely JSON"? How are you determining that? Also, if that's the case, all of the answers here are incorrect, since none of them parse the JSON.

Comment: @Andrew JSON is *always* a string.  The code in the question is a JS object literal.

Comment: this is an example from a JSON file. It was originally a csv converted to JSON. In the future I would clean this server side and load into and API to hit but for the sake of figuring out the answer its a sample.

Comment: While you can literally paste the JSON in this answer into just about any JSON validator that I can find from any searching and have the validator tell you that this is valid JSON, I'm pretty confident that both of you are being pedantic here, and you're ignoring the actual question being asked for no reason...

Answer (score 2):

You can use array function map:

```js
const data = [
    {
      "Month/Year": "2019-09",
      "group": "blue",
      "flights": "668,620"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "blue",
        "flights": "662,520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-09",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "662,520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "678,520"
    }
]

const result = data.map(item => {item.flights = item.flights.replace(",",""); return item})
console.log(result)
```

Comment: This has a side-effect of changing the original data. You shouldn't do that if you're using map to make a new array.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with simple map and replace methods.

```js
let newArray = array.map(obj => {
  obj.flights = obj.flights.replace(/,/g, '');
  
  return obj;
})
```

Comment: This updates the original data, just like [a previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58615243/215552). That means you've now got two identical arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you call this array `arr`, you can access each of the desired fields by using `elem.flights` (for each element of the array), and remove its comma by using `replace(",", "")`:

```js
arr = [
    {
      "Month/Year": "2019-09",
      "group": "blue",
      "flights": "668,620"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "blue",
        "flights": "662,520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-09",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "662,520"
    },
    {
        "Month/Year": "2019-10",
        "group": "green",
        "flights": "678,520"
    }
];

for(var elem of arr) {
  elem.flights = elem.flights.replace(",", "");
  console.log(elem.flights);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There are a few different ways to loop over an array in javascript.  I like good old fashioned `for` loops.

```
var obj = [
{
  "Month/Year": "2019-09",
  "group": "blue",
  "flights": "668,620"
},
{
    "Month/Year": "2019-10",
    "group": "blue",
    "flights": "662,520"
},
{
    "Month/Year": "2019-09",
    "group": "green",
    "flights": "662,520"
},
{
    "Month/Year": "2019-10",
    "group": "green",
    "flights": "678,520"
}];

for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{
    obj[i]['flights'] = obj[i]['flights'].split(',').join('');
}
```

Using `.split(',')` converts the string to an array and then `.join('')` converts it back to a string but w/o a separator.